# Get the first item out of a Ruby array in a hash

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby hash that looks like this:

```
h = {"side1"=>["green", "Green"], "side2"=>["verde", "Verde"]}
```

How can I get the first (or last) item at a particular key in the hash?

Comment: `puts h['side2].first` is perfectly valid syntax. `puts h['side2][0]` will also work.

Comment: I don't get why people are downvoting this question. I'm new to stackoverflow, but it seems like the downvoting here is a kind of rtfm.  If the question is clear and you can learn from, that's good in my book

Comment: ^ IMO In terms of requirement, not sure why one would require this facility. If data structures are used properly and also if implementation is equally good (without hacks); then you wouldn't need this. After all you pick hash elements using key and nothing else or we use array. Also question should just be 'first element of hash'. Array in hash would mean something else.

Comment: I think I can explain the downvotes: it is clear you didn't even try your 'pseudo-code' because had you tried it you would have noticed it worked. You would have spent less time discovering your answer in `irb` than typing your question into StackOverflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, your example pseudo code in your question is correct.

For your hash

```
h = {
   "side1" => ["green", "Green"], 
   "side2" => ["verde", "Verde"]
}
```

the keys are `'side1'` and `'side2'` (with their values right of the hashrocket)

So, `h['side2'].first` says that for the value of key `'side2'`, get the first element in the value `["verde", "Verde"]`, which is an array.  `h['side2'][0]` would also work.  the alias `first` is a convenience method.

To get the last element of an array without having to know how big it is, use a negative index. e.g. `h['side2'][-1]`, which is equivalent to `h['side2'][1]` in this case.

Note that keys in a hash are particular about whether it is a string or symbol. That is `h[:side2]` would return nil, as the key hasn't been set.  Rails has a class `HashWithIndifferentAccess` that treats symbols and strings as equivalent keys.

**EDIT**

I should have mentioned that I tested my answer in `irb`. `irb` is a great way to test your ideas about what may and may not work. In your terminal prompt, type `irb`, enter, and play with ruby.

Comment: thanks! I didn't try my own answer because I assumed it wouldn't work. I'm new to using the Ruby Hash.

Comment: no problem.  irb is really useful when you want to play around with functionality, especially because ruby is so dynamic you can do anything.  I use it all the time, like (modified to be pasteable on one line):  class String; def wild; "wild"; end; end; bar = "foo"; puts bar.wild; def bar.wild; "and crazy"; end; puts bar.wild

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a similar situation where I arbitrarily wanted the "first" entry from the hash for some test code. That's not exactly what this question is about, but it came up in the search I ran so figure it might do likewise for others.

Of course "first item" is arbitrary in a hash, but the keys method will return a list of all keys sorted by some magic. If you like that sort order, then you can get the "first" method with

```
h[h.keys.first]
```

Answer (score 6):

Any hash has keys and values
you can simply make

```
hash.values.first
hash.values.last
hash.keys.first
hash.keys.last
```

So you will have the array of values you want in case first or last

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `puts h["side2"].first` should work. I guess this goes to show that Ruby follows the principle of least-surprise, where your pseudo-code turned out to be the same as the actual code. :-)